# sfdisk from util-linux 2.25.2 reporting (c,h,s) warnings on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, partition

At [sfdisk shows impossible value and (c,h,s) expected on another system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355447/159562) I report about the following warnings when looking at the partition layout of my SD card or USB drives on my Raspbian (Jessie) system with `sudo sfdisk -lV /dev/mmcblk0` (sfdisk from util-linux 2.25.2):

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3923936 cylinders, 4 heads, 16 sectors/track
Units: cylinders of 32768 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1        128    2143    2016      64512    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
                start: (c,h,s) expected (128,0,1) found (0,130,3)
                end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (8,138,2)
/dev/mmcblk0p2       2144  329823  327680   10485760   83  Linux
                start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (8,138,3)
                end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (1023,254,63)
/dev/mmcblk0p3     329824  591967  262144    8388608   83  Linux
                start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (1023,254,63)
                end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (1023,254,63)
/dev/mmcblk0p4     591968  3497439  2905472   92975104    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
                start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (1023,254,63)
                end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (1023,254,63)
sfdisk: Warning: no primary partition is marked bootable (active)
This does not matter for LILO, but the DOS MBR will not boot this disk.
sfdisk: start of partition 1 has impossible value for head: 130 (should be in 0-3)
```

Since I don't see these warnings with sfdisk from util-linux 2.29.1 when the SD card is plugged into another computer via USB card reader, I believe it is a problem of the older version of sfdisk of Raspbian Jessie and that other users should see this, too.

Can anybody confirm these warnings on their Raspbian system?

Comment: @Milliways I have edited my question to make it clear that this is directly related to Raspberry Pi. So please remove the hold. I want info from other RPi users. Why don't you post your sfdisk output here instead?

Comment: @Jacobm001 I have edited my question to make it clear that this is directly related to Raspberry Pi. So please remove the hold. I want info from other RPi users. Why don't you post your sfdisk output here instead?

Comment: I have reopened your question, though I don't have an answer for you.